# How to put two tables next to each other?

Tags: tables, mathjax

I'm using MathJax on Math.SE and would like to place two matrices next to one another.

When using an `array` followed by another `array`, they are not placed on the same line/row as can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977453/3-colourings-of-a-3%C3%973-table-with-one-of-3-colors-up-to-symmetries/2977685#2977685) (despite separating the content with text):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Please be more specific about your typesetting needs. E.g., do the two tables have the same number of rows and/or columns?

Comment: I like you Werner! You are my man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MathJax-specific content, you should place two `array`s within the same display math environment `$$`...`$$`:

```
$$
  \begin{array} {|r|r|r|}
    \hline
      & X &   \\
    \hline
    X &   & X \\
    \hline
      & X &   \\
    \hline
  \end{array}
  \begin{array} {|r|r|r|}
    \hline
      & X &   \\
    \hline
    X &   & X \\
    \hline
      & X &   \\
    \hline
  \end{array}
$$
```

[image]

Comment: Hi again, can you tell me plese how to color a particular cell?

Comment: @Aqua: This does not seem to be implemented yet. See [this github issue](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2634).